# SF Service proxy calling stateless service instances

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

In my SF application a stateful `Worker` service communicates with a stateless `Logging` service using service remoting. The stateful `Worker` service creates the `Logging` proxy in its constructor using [`ServiceProxy.Create<ILoggingService>(loggingServiceUri)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.client.serviceproxy.create?view=azure-dotnet) and keeps the returned reference for its entire lifetime. There are  several stateless `Logging` service instances running on the cluster (i. e. `Instance Count == -1`). My question is:

Are calls to the `ILoggingService` proxy form the `Worker` service routed to different `Logging` service instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you are using SF remoting to talk to a stateless service, your message will be delivered to a random instance. The proxy will keep track of healthy instances for you, and deal with transient errors.